# In my settings.py file I set DEBUG = False, but website still debugs on webserver (nginx)

Tags: django, webserver

This is the settings.py file. As you can see, both debug and template debug are set to False. Yet, if I try to trigger a 404 error, I don't get a regular 404 error or the one from my 404.html file. The 404 error that it returns is the one from Django where it says :

"You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page."

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'this is a secret'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mywebsite.com','my website\'s ip']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'myapp',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project.urls'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/django/django_project/django_project/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Help!

Comment: Are you sure your app isn't using a different settings file?

Comment: You might have to restart your wsgi server when you change the settings.

Comment: rnevius, the app does not have its own settings file. Håken Lid, I restarted nginx, nothing changed.

Comment: Restarting nginx will not achieve anything. You need to reload gunicorn or whatever wsgi server you are using. kill -HUP will do in most cases. In some cases touch wsgi.py also does the trick

Comment: Restarting gunicorn did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(just to mark that this question is answered - by @e4c5)

summary:
if your django application is running as a separate daemon (manage.py runfcgi, gunicorn, uwsgi etc.), every time you change source file (this includes settings.py) - application need to be restarted

regarding templates - this depends how you load them - if you use any form of cache - you should reload daemon, without cache - it should be reloaded automatically

make sure that your date and time is always set properly, sometimes reported errors include that after code upgrade application is still running old one - in most cases there is an issue with the dates - compiled .pyc files are newer than your source .py ones, `./manage.py clean_pyc` after deployment is a good thing to do.